# ASP.net access controls dynamically

Tags: asp.net, controls

i have a table which looks similar to this

```
<asp:TableRow><asp:TableCell>Question 1</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID ="Question1Text"></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow><asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"><asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow><asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow><asp:TableCell>Question 2</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID ="Question2Text"></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
               <asp:TableRow><asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server"><asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow><asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow>
```

i want to be able to systematically acces table cells with ID's for example

```
for (int i = 1; i<3 ; i++)
{
// i want to be able to access the table cell with the ID Question1Text then Question2Text and so on 
}
```

is this even possible ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    string id = string.Format("Question{0}Text", i);
    TableCell cell = (TableCell) FindControl(id);

    // do whatever you want with the cell
}
```

You can use FindControl to search a control tree for controls with the given identifier string.

Though I must say, I don't think I would write code like that. I would simply define a regular HTML table, and then have `<asp:Literal>` controls where I needed to specifically control the text. What you've got here is rather difficult for me to parse and understand (is it generated by the designer, maybe?)

Comment: this code was written by me, the only reason I want to do it this way is that the questions are stored in a database, i have about 30 questions and i thought it would be easier to dynamically add the question text in !! i want to create some sort of feedback from, if you have any ideas to make it easier that would be great !!

Comment: @c11ada: look at the data bound controls, such as the DataList and  Repeater.